# I can't see why I'm getting a 'cannot resolve symbol' error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oop, gradle

Why am I getting a cannot resolve symbol (red text) in my java class?  I know this has something to do with my `Gradle` file but even if it does, I can't see why because I'm pretty sure everything in it is correct.

What I've done so far:

1. File > Invalidate Caches/Restart.
2. Build > Clean Project.
3. Build > Rebuild Project.
4. Close Android-Studio & restart my computer.

None of them worked.

[Java class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BANgp.png)

[**Gradle**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAiVi.png)

Comment: Don't link screenshots. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40897729/edit) your post to include your actual code and point out where the error is.

Comment: @nanoSecond24 please edit your post to include the actual code as opposed to images of the code. Images of code are frowned upon as they don't allow people to cut and paste the code, which many do in order to ascertain the issue(s).

Comment: Do you have a class named `Override` in the same package?

Comment: @MikeT Got it, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please post code, not images to code.

Notice the red font on Activity.  That means the Activity class isn't recognized.  You need to either import Activity, or extend AppCompatActivity instead.  Right now you're extending a class that isn't imported so the compiler doesn't know it. That makes the override annotation is invalid (for an override annotation to be valid, it needs to be know the parent class so it can check if the signature of the function is the same as one in the parent class).

Comment: Why would that cause error *"cannot resolve symbol"* on `@Override`? Shouldn't that have marked `Activity` instead of `@Override`?

Comment: Its probably marking both-  notice that Activity is red instead of black.

Comment: Really? Guess I'm used to my Eclipse using the red squiggly underline to show errors. Android Studio is different?

Comment: Its showing 2 errors.  One on Activity, one on @Override.  And yes, different IDEs use different methods of showing errors.

Comment: Sorry, temporarily forgot that Android Studio is not based on Eclipse anymore.

Comment: But your answer is then confusing too, because it implies that the only error is the annotation error, but the "cannot resolve symbol" error applies to `Activity`, not `@Override`. `@Override` would have a different error, and it is a "cascade" error, i.e. the first error is the cause of the second error.

Comment: It is.  YOu didn't import Activity-  you imported AppCompatActivity.  Then you extended Activity, a class it knows nothing about.  Since it doesn't know anything about Activity the @Override tag on anything is invalid, as it can't know if its a valid Override with an unknown parent.

Comment: Not me, I'm not the question author. I was trying to get you to improve the answer so I can up-vote it, since you did recognize the real error, i.e. the use of undefined class `Activity`, but I find your explanation confusing and it could be made clearer. You could also address OP's mistaken *"I know this has something to do with my Gradel file"*.

Comment: Ah, sorry didn't notice the usernames.  I've expanded on my answer a bit.